# Cosine_similarity between dataframe and subset dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, scikit-learn

Basically I have a dataframe with movies as rows, a column 'title' and a column 'soup'. This last column contains the overview of a movie and collaborators in the form of a String.

I have a second dataframe with a subset of movies. (and thus the 'soup' is also a subset of the full DF)

Now with the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

df_all = spark.createDataFrame(
     [
         ('The terminator', 'This is info about the terminator'),
         ('News', 'This is some info about the news'),
         ('Superman', 'This is some info about Superman')
     ],
     ['title', 'soup'] # Columns
)

df_subset = spark.createDataFrame(
     [
         ('The terminator', 'This is info about the terminator'),
         ('Superman', 'This is some info about Superman')
     ],
     ['title', 'soup'] # Columns
)

count = CountVectorizer()
count_matrix = count.fit_transform(df_all['soup'])
count_matrix_subset = count.fit_transform(df_subset['soup'])

cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(count_matrix, count_matrix_subset)
```

But this is impossible since the two matrices have a different shape (because the 'soup' of the subset matrix is a subset)

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: One fundamental problem is that you are using fit_transform again, fitting the `countvectorizer()` second time.

Comment: @KimTang, you should be able to reproduce it now.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal, so whats the solution for it?

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fitting and transforming your count vectorizer changing the vocabulary from that of the full data to that of the subset data. This changes the length of vector representation you are creating for the data and subset of data. Instead, just fit once and use that to transform the data 2 times, once for full data and other for subset. This will result in the same dimensional representation (dimension will be equal to the vocab of the full data)

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

#dummy data and subset
full = ['info about the terminator', 'This is some info about the news', 'This is some info about Superman']
subset = ['This is info about the terminator', 'This is some info about Superman']

#fit count vectorizer
count = CountVectorizer()
count.fit(full)

#transform the full and subset
count_matrix = count.transform(full)
count_matrix_subset = count.transform(subset)

print('count_matrix: ',count_matrix.shape)
print('count_matrix_subset: ',count_matrix_subset.shape)

#Consine similarty on the common dimension
cs = cosine_similarity(count_matrix, count_matrix_subset)
print('Cosine similarity matrix',cs.shape)
```

```
count_matrix:  (3, 9)
count_matrix_subset:  (2, 9)
Cosine similarity matrix (3, 2)
```